The following UnsupportedError was thrown building SideTitlesWidget(dirty): Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
im trying to display data with flutter from firebase realtime database. the display will be shown as linechart data with fl_chart. to display this data, the linechart is wrap with streambuilder. but i got error The following UnsupportedError was thrown building SideTitlesWidget(dirty): Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
my flutter code :
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class DataPoint {
  double value;
  int timestamp; // Epoch timestamp in milliseconds
  DataPoint(this.value, this.timestamp);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Value: $value, Timestamp: $timestamp';
  }
}

int widthGraph = 600;
int startIndex = 0;
int lastIndex = 0;
bool _isCurved = false;

RangeValues _rangeValues = const RangeValues(0, 4);

class DataPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<DataPage> createState() => _DataPageState();
}

class _DataPageState extends State<DataPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget bottomTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta, double chartWidth) {
    if (value % 1 != 0) {
      return Container();
    }
    return SideTitleWidget(
      axisSide: meta.axisSide,
      space: 20,
      child: Text(meta.formattedValue),
    );
  }

  var dbr = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Monitoring Gas'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 400,
              child: StreamBuilder(
                stream:
                    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('SensorData').onValue,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }

                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                  }

                  if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                      snapshot.data!.snapshot.value == null) {
                    return const Center(child: Text('No data available'));
                  }

                  var data =
                      snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>;

                  List<DataPoint> dataList1 = [];
                  List<DataPoint> dataList2 = [];

                  data.forEach((key, value) {
                    // Assuming "Device1" holds integer values
                    dataList1.add(DataPoint(
                        double.parse(value["Device1"].toString()),
                        int.parse(key.toString())));
                    dataList2.add(DataPoint(
                        double.parse(value["Device2"].toString()),
                        int.parse(key.toString())));
                  });
                  print(dataList1);

                  return LineChart(LineChartData(
                      lineBarsData: [
                        LineChartBarData(
                          spots: List.generate(
                            dataList1.length,
                            (index) => dataList1[index].timestamp.toDouble() >=
                                        dataList1[startIndex]
                                            .timestamp
                                            .toDouble() &&
                                    dataList1[index].timestamp.toDouble() <=
                                        dataList1[lastIndex]
                                            .timestamp
                                            .toDouble()
                                ? FlSpot(
                                    dataList1[index].timestamp.toDouble(),
                                    dataList1[index].value,
                                  )
                                : null,
                          )
                              .where((spot) => spot != null)
                              .cast<FlSpot>()
                              .toList(),
                          isCurved: _isCurved,
                          color: const Color.fromARGB(83, 39, 176, 85),
                          barWidth: 2,
                          isStrokeCapRound: true,
                          dotData: const FlDotData(
                            show: true,
                          ),
                          belowBarData: BarAreaData(
                              show: true,
                              color: const Color.fromARGB(78, 39, 176, 85)),
                        ),
                      ],
                      titlesData: FlTitlesData(
                        topTitles: const AxisTitles(
                            sideTitles: SideTitles(showTitles: false)),
                        leftTitles: AxisTitles(
                            axisNameWidget:
                                const Text('Gas particle on air(ppm)'),
                            sideTitles: SideTitles(
                              showTitles: true,
                              getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
                                return Text(
                                  value.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 8),
                                );
                              },
                            )),
                        bottomTitles: AxisTitles(
                            axisNameWidget: const Text('Timestamp'),
                            sideTitles: SideTitles(
                              showTitles: true,
                              getTitlesWidget: (value, meta) {
                                DateTime dateTime =
                                    DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                                        value.toInt() * 1000);
                                return RotatedBox(
                                  quarterTurns: 1,
                                  child: Text(
                                    DateFormat('h:mm a').format(dateTime),
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 8),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                            )),
                      )));
                },
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 100,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [Text("MQ-2 : "), Text("-- ppm")],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 100,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [Text("MQ-7"), Text("-- ppm")],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 100,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [Text("MQ-4"), Text("-- ppm")],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 100,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [Text("MQ-135"), Text("-- ppm")],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      height: 100,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
                      child: const Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [Text("MQ-136"), Text("-- ppm")],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  void showNotification(BuildContext context, String message) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
        content: Text(message.toString())));
  }
}

my terminal debug error :
D/EGL_emulation(10746): app_time_stats: avg=54988.80ms min=36.06ms max=219347.78ms count=4
I/flutter (10746): 2

══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following UnsupportedError was thrown building SideTitlesWidget(dirty):
Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  SideTitlesWidget
  SideTitlesWidget:file:///C:/Users/pegug/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/fl_chart-0.67.0/lib/src/chart/base/axis_chart/axis_chart_scaffold_widget.dart:105:9

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      double.toInt (dart:core-patch/double.dart)
#1      double.truncate (dart:core-patch/double.dart:195:21)
#2      double.~/ (dart:core-patch/double.dart:56:38)
#3      Utils.getEfficientInterval (package:fl_chart/src/utils/utils.dart:137:48)
#4      SideTitlesWidget.makeWidgets (package:fl_chart/src/chart/base/axis_chart/side_titles/side_titles_widget.dart:116:17)
#5      SideTitlesWidget.build (package:fl_chart/src/chart/base/axis_chart/side_titles/side_titles_widget.dart:208:32)
#6      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5550:49)
#7      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5480:15)
#8      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
#9      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
#10     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
#11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
#12     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6893:36)
#13     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6905:32)
#14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
#15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
#16     _LayoutBuilderElement._layout.layoutCallback (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:155:18)
#17     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2844:19)
#18     _LayoutBuilderElement._layout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:173:12)
#19     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2686:59)
#20     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1097:15)
#21     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2686:14)
#22     RenderConstrainedLayoutBuilder.rebuildIfNecessary (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:248:7)
#23     _RenderLayoutBuilder.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:331:5)
#24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#25     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#26     ChildLayoutHelper.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/layout_helper.dart:52:11)
#27     RenderFlex._computeSizes (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:809:43)
#28     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:904:32)
#29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#30     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#31     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:280:14)
#32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#33     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#34     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#36     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#37     RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:21)
#38     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#39     RenderBox.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2389:11)
#40     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:211:28)
#41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#42     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:139:12)
#43     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:361:11)
#44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2575:7)
#45     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:601:13)
#46     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1555:12)
#47     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1464:20)
#48     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:2414:7)
#49     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1051:18)
#50     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1064:15)
#51     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:582:23)
#52     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:991:13)
#53     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:448:5)
#54     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1386:15)
#55     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1311:9)
#56     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1169:5)
#57     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:312:13)
#58     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:399:5)
#59     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:283:31)

════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
Another exception was thrown: RenderLineChart object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: RenderDecoratedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 600 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#38474 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderLayoutBuilder#47c9e relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#36c43 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
I/flutter (10746): 4
Another exception was thrown: Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
Another exception was thrown: Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
Another exception was thrown: RenderLineChart object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: RenderDecoratedBox object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: RenderPadding object was given an infinite size during layout.
Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart': Failed assertion: line 600 pos 12: 'size.isFinite': is not true.
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#975a2 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderLayoutBuilder#9f1fd relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#b9766 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
Another exception was thrown: Unsupported operation: Infinity or NaN toInt
W/System  (10746): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
D/FirebaseAuth(10746): Notifying id token listeners about user ( n6GZErmNaphkh5vamRulwaOsJoe2 )

the error seems likely about the widget, so i have tried removing the sidetitle widget, wrapping the streambuilder with expanded. but the following method i tried still got the same error.
